# Decision Macro - Making decision based on three columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to program a macro which should follow as this:

1. Take a look into column A and find what starts on "SAP" (e.g.: SAP-23F)
2. If it is not SAP.. -> blank cell in column D; If yes -> Check column B and C
3. Checking column B and C -> If in those is anything found starting with "Kal" (e.g. Kal c.2) then write into column D "Kal", if not, then write "Obr"

I started with a very easy example to train on it however even this one doesn't work. My example is looking into column 1, if there is A then it is shall look into column 2 if not, it writes into column 3 a negative answer. If in column 2 is B or C then it writes into column 3 an answer. See below:

```
Sub Test()
    score1 = ActiveSheet.Range("S3:S6").Value
    If score1 = A Then
        Call Test1
    Else
        result = "C"
    End If
    ActiveSheet.Range("U3:U6").Value = result
End Sub

Sub Test1()
    score2 = ActiveSheet.Range("T3:T6").Value
    If score2 = B Then
        result = "X"
    Else
        result = "Y"
    End If
    ActiveSheet.Range("U3:U6").Value = result
End Sub
```

My question is what is wrong in my example and how to adapt it to be used in the real case mentioned at the beginning.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: To use a "contains" comparision, don't use `score1 = A`, use, `score1 Like A*` (beginning with A), or even `score 1 Like *A*` (containing A)

Comment: Do you need this to be in `vba`? You can do this with formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this code helps you.
It basically do what you described, using the "Sheet1" sheet and without any headers on the table:

```
Sub SAPKalObr()

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Finds the last used row at column 1
        For r = 1 To LastRow 'Iterate between every used row at the first column
            If .Cells(r, 1) Like "SAP*" Then 'Testing for starting with SAP on the first column
                If .Cells(r, 2) Like "Kal*" Or .Cells(r, 3) Like "Kal*" Then 'SAP? Testing for Kal on the second or third column
                    .Cells(r, 4).Value = "Kal" 'Returning Kal
                Else
                    .Cells(r, 4).Value = "Obr" 'No Kal? Returning Obr
                End If
            Else
                .Cells(r, 4).Value = " " 'No SAP? Returning blank
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This assumes that values like "SAP" and "KAL" should be found on the same row, but I'm not sure that is the case.

Comment: That was how I interpretated, actually. Could you explain your interpretation, please?

Comment: I was going off of "If in those [i.e. column B and C] is anything found starting with 'Kal'". OP should clarify...

Answer (score 0):

A “formula” approach:

```
Sub Main()
    With Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Offset(,3)
        .FormulaR1C1= "=IF(LEFT(RC1,3)=""SAP"",IF(OR(LEFT(RC2,3)=""Kal"",LEFT(RC3,3)=""Kal""),""Kal"",""Obr""),"""")" 
        .Value = .Value
   End With 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

***[SOLVED]***: mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1064325-decision-macro.html

**Thanks a lot for all your help!**

```
Sub MyTest()

    Dim lr As Long
    Dim r As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'   Find last row with data in column A
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'   Loop through all rows in column A starting with row 2
    For r = 2 To lr
'       Check to see if column A does not start with "SAP"
        If Left(Cells(r, "A"), 3) <> "SAP" Then
            Cells(r, "D") = ""
        Else
'           Check to see if columns B or C start with "Kal"
            If (Left(Cells(r, "B"), 3) = "Kal") Or (Left(Cells(r, "c"), 3) = "Kal") Then
                Cells(r, "D") = "Kal"
            Else
                Cells(r, "D") = "Obr"
            End If
        End If
    Next r

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```